# Remove space between posts [bootstrap]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to remove space between post without image and post below, here is image, so if post don't have image, below that post should not have space:

[image]

here is code:

```
<div class="container">
           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">

                      <img src="http://placehold.it/460x250/e67e22/ffffff&text=HTML5" class="img-responsive" />
                    <div class="content">
                        <h4>NASLOV</h4>
                       <p>
                           Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
                           Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                           unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                       </p>
                   </div>

           </div>
           <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">

                      <img src="http://placehold.it/460x250/e67e22/ffffff&text=HTML5" class="img-responsive" />
                    <div class="content">
                        <h4>NASLOV</h4>
                       <p>
                           Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
                           Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                           unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                       </p>
                   </div>

           </div>
           <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">

                      <img src="http://placehold.it/460x250/e67e22/ffffff&text=HTML5" class="img-responsive" />
                    <div class="content">
                        <h4>NASLOV</h4>
                       <p>
                           Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
                           Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                           unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                       </p>
                   </div>

           </div>
           <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">

                      <img src="http://placehold.it/460x250/e67e22/ffffff&text=HTML5" class="img-responsive" />
                    <div class="content">
                        <h4>NASLOV</h4>
                       <p>
                           Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
                           Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                           unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                       </p>
                   </div>

           </div>

           <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">

                      <img src="http://placehold.it/460x250/e67e22/ffffff&text=HTML5" class="img-responsive" />
                    <div class="content">
                        <h4>NASLOV</h4>
                       <p>
                           Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
                           Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                           unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                       </p>
                   </div>

           </div>
           <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">

                      <img src="http://placehold.it/460x250/e67e22/ffffff&text=HTML5" class="img-responsive" />
                    <div class="content">
                        <h4>NASLOV</h4>
                       <p>
                           Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
                           Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                           unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                       </p>
                   </div>

           </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">

                      <img src="http://placehold.it/460x250/e67e22/ffffff&text=HTML5" class="img-responsive" />
                    <div class="content">
                        <h4>NASLOV</h4>
                       <p>
                           Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
                           Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                           unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                       </p>
                   </div>

           </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

here is live: http://www.bootply.com/sfmRGTiKS4
Any idea? :)

Answer (score 0):

To get what you want your template does not have to be arranged in rows but only for columns in this way the elements within each column will be in place under each other without space constraint imposed by the line. For do this remove the external `<div class="row">`